# Can Ubuntu be installed on a Dell Inspiron 1501?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, ubuntu-10.04, compatibility

I hope to format my Dell Inspiron 1501 that is currently running Windows Vista, and install Ubuntu 12.0 or 13.0. Is there any Windows software to detect the hardware's compatibility with Ubuntu?

I'm  worried that after formatting, my Inspiron will become a brick.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to test is to download the Ubuntu CD and boot from it. Most modern Linux distributions, including Ubuntu, are distributed as a ["Live CD"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) which means you can boot from the CD directly and try the Operating Syustem without making any changes to your hard drive.

That said, the vast majority of hardware is correctly recognized by Linux and you should have no problems. In my experience, [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/), which is based on Ubuntu, is better at recognizing and configuring laptop hardware.

A great resource for Linux on latops (and the first [google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20laptops) for "Linux laptops") is [linux on laptops](http://www.linux-on-laptops.com). [According to them](http://fosser.wikispaces.com/Ubuntu+on+Inspiron+1501), worked almost perfectly (some tweaking required for wireless) out of the box for Ubuntu 7.04. It is probably perfect by now.